# Game Center p2p with 3G and wifi

Tags: iphone, game-center

I have a basic p2p setup with gamecenter and it currently works on Wifi, a local network. Players connect to the same network and they can play a game.

How does one set this up for a 3g network. So that players dont need to be connected to a wifi network.

Can this be done and still be handled by apples servers?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [game kit programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/FindingPeerswithPeerPicker/FindingPeerswithPeerPicker.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH102-SW1) to see how you can create an adhoc peer to peer connection over Bluetooth and it also describes in limited detail how to connect to a peer over the Internet which would include a 3G connection.